# Why does the socket.on function gets repeated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My programs works like this: When I click dice in index.html, it starts happy() function in javascript file, which signals to generate the random number in app.js. This random number is then received by the javascript file and then randomNum() is called.
My problem: When I open the html file and then click the dice, it is good. But, when I again click on the dice, I found out that the socket.on of the happy() function was repeated twice. Again, when I clicked the dice, the socket.on was repeated three times and so on. What is going on? I am just getting started on node.js, so any help would be appreciated.
My codes:
Dice in index.html

```
<div id="dice" onclick="happy()" style="background-image:url(/client/Images/dice.gif)"></div>
```

Javascript file

```
var num1 = [];

var socket = io();
function happy(){
        console.log(num1);
        num1 = [];
        socket.emit('happy',{
            reason:true
        });
        
        socket.on('rannumber',function(data){
            console.log(data.reason);
            if(0< data.reason <7){
                num1.push(data.reason);
                randomNum();
            }
        });
}
```

app.js file

```
var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 
    console.log('socket connection');
        
    socket.on('happy', function(data){
        console.log(data.reason);
        if (data.reason = true){
            console.log('generating random number')
            var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            socket.emit('rannumber',{
                reason: number
                
            });
            console.log(number)
        }
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this outside the `happy()` function:

```
        socket.on('rannumber',function(data){
            console.log(data.reason);
            if(0< data.reason <7){
                num1.push(data.reason);
                randomNum();
            }
        });
```

Currently every time `happy()` function is called a new callback is registered for `socket.on('rannumber', ...)`. So, whenever `rannumber` is emitted, each of those registered callbacks will be called. You need to register this callback only once.

You can try this:

```
var num1 = [];

var socket = io();

socket.on('rannumber',function(data){
    console.log(data.reason);
    if(0< data.reason <7) {
        num1.push(data.reason);
        randomNum();
    }
});

function happy(){
    console.log(num1);
    num1 = [];
    socket.emit('happy',{
        reason:true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem that I had. But, I face another problem. I will now look whether this new format had created the problem.